# Convert string to int in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

Here i am trying to multiply both  ticketPrice(ng-model) and selceted numberOfTickets(ng-model) but i am always getting NAN as total

```
<tr>
     <td ng-model="ticketPrice">5</td>
     <td>
       <select class="form-control" ng-model="numberOfTickets" 
            ng-options="n for n in [] | range:1:15"  >
           <option value="">--Select No. of Tickets--</option>                                                    
       </select>
     </td>
     <td class="text-primary text-center"><strong ng-model="ticketsTotalPrice">{{ ticketPrice * numberOfTickets }} </strong></td>
    </tr>
```

Please give a solution

Thank you!

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<td>` elements.

Comment: HI @georgeawg try this `<span ng-init="price=100" ></span>`

Comment: then what should i use for ticket price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click here to check fiddle example

```
<span ng-init="price=100" ></span>
<select name="" id="" ng-model="noOfTic">
  <option value="" selected>select ticket</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
{{price * noOfTic}}
```

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/29715/)

Comment: ng-model="ticketPrice"  is dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-bind not ng-model

```
<strong ng-bind="ticketPrice * numberOfTickets"></strong>
```